# ^ meaning in "let's build a compiler" code

Tags: pascal

In Jack Crenshaw's "Lets' build a compiler" what does the ^I mean in this statement:

```
 const TAB = ^I;
```

He also uses ^G in one his functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Free Pascal Language Reference](ftp://ftp.freepascal.org/fpc/docs-pdf/ref.pdf):

> Also,  the caret character ( ^ ) can be used in combination with a
>   letter to specify a character with ASCII value less than 27. Thus ^G
>   equals #7 - G is the seventh letter in the alphabet.
>   The compiler is rather sloppy about the characters it allows after the caret, but in general
>   one should assume only letters.

The result is a one-byte ASCII character constant. `I` is the 9th letter in the alphabet. And the ASCII value 9 is – no surprise – the TAB character.

Comment: What would the c/c++ equivalent be of that statement?

Comment: `const char TAB = '\t';` or `const char TAB = '\011';` or `const char TAB = '\x09';`. Note that Pascal allows for constants with an implicitly derived type while C/C++ forces you to specify the type. 011 is the octal representation of 9.

Answer (score 2):

It's Control-I. This translates to ASCII char-9, which is the character for Tab. Similarly Ctrl-G is ASCII char-7, which is the character for the BEL (literally bell), which usually generates a beep from a console.